# Can we deploy a workflow created as a farm solution?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, visual-studio

Can we deploy a workflow created as a farm solution on a remote server and associate it with a particular document library within the site?

Comment: What is the main issue? To deploy farm solution WSP when you have no access to remote server (can't run PowerShell) or how to associate WF with Document Library within the site? I mean, do you have problems in deployment or in association? Or both? Could you clarify, please.

Comment: I have access to Remote Server, have Developed a Sequential worklow on my local machine as a farm solution. Hence need to deploye it on the server site and associate it with a document Library.Being a Sequential Workflow I am not able to activate the solution on seerver site...

Comment: Have you already deployed your solution using PowerShell?

Comment: And after deploy them you must activate the solution.

Comment: Yes I have deployed it and its activated ?? am i missing Something

Comment: When I tried to deploy a Reusable Workflow as a Farm Solution, I found that it would deploy and activate, but then it seemed to have issues on each site. I think the issue was something to do with the workflow name already being in use. Not sure how to solve this.